# How do I check for the existence of a process without a failed exit code being returned?

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit, pidof

I’m using Amazon Linux.  I want to start a process provided one isn’t running already.  This is a bash script I embed within a Jenkins Maven job.  So I have

```
pids=$(pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb)
if [ ! -n "$pids" ]; then
    Xvfb :0 -screen 5 1024x768x8 &
fi
```

Unfortunately, if there is no process, the line “pids=$(pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb)” returns a failing exit code and none of the other lines following are executed.  Is there a way I can write the above such that no failed exit codes will be returned?

Comment: Just use `if ! pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb; then : do something; fi`

Comment: I tried "if ! pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb; then : Xvfb :0 -screen 5 1024x768x8 &; fi" and got the error, "syntax error near unexpected token `;'".

Comment: Should be `if ! pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb; then Xvfb :0 -screen 5 1024x768x8 & fi"` if you want to run command in background.

Comment: `if ! pgrep Xvfb; then ...` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running under `set -e`, add `|| true` after a command to ignore a failure of that command.

```
pids=$(pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb || true)
if [ ! -n "$pids" ]; then
    Xvfb :0 -screen 5 1024x768x8 &
fi
```

But since `pidof` returns a nonzero status if no processes are found, you could directly test its return status instead of checking whether its output is empty.

```
if ! pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    Xvfb :0 -screen 5 1024x768x8 &
fi
```